# How to apply Google Apps Script to filtered emails?

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

I currently have a script in place to auto reply to messages sent over the weekend, checking for unread messages in the last 5 minutes, and then replying and marking as read.

I was wondering if it were possible to only have this script look for unread messages INSIDE a specific folder/filter. The reason for this is we have lots of different emails going to this box, and we don't want auto replies to most emails, just some, which have been filtered.

If it is not possible to have a script look inside a filter, is it possible to only have to reply to messages that match a certain condition?

This is the current script I have in place, running every five minutes:

```
function autoReply() {
var interval = 5;    //  if the script runs every 5 minutes; change otherwise
  var date = new Date();
  var day = date.getDay();
  var hour = date.getHours();
  if ([6,0].indexOf(day) > -1 || (day == 1 && hour < 10) || (day == 5 && hour >= 15)) {
    var timeFrom = Math.floor(date.valueOf()/1000) - 60 * interval;
    var threads = GmailApp.search('is:inbox after:' + timeFrom);
    for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
      if (threads[i].isUnread()){
      threads[i].reply("Thank you for reaching CTGINC. Your email is very important to us, one of our customer service experts will respond within the next 24-48 hours. Thank you!");
      threads[i].markRead();
      threads[i].markImportant();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Requirement:

Find unread emails inside a label.

---

#### Solution:

Enhance your current `GmailApp.search()` query to include this criteria.

---

#### Example:

```
//replace "labelname" with the name of your label
var threads = GmailApp.search('in:labelname is:unread after:' + timeFrom);
```

---

#### Explanation:

As you can see in the query, it's only looking for threads inside that specific label that are unread and recieved before your `var timeFrom`.

`GmailApp.search()` uses the same search operators as the search bar at the top of your Gmail. It's worth reading up on them [here](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190?hl=en), there are loads of different possibilities.

Comment: I think this answer is more succinct than mine.

Answer (score -1):

Cat, have you played with having your filters apply labels and then using getLabels()?

Comment: All of the messages already have a label applied, "Customer Support". How would I use getLabels in this scenario?

Comment: @CatBlanket see [the docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-thread#getLabels())